# Limit string length of all cells in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi is there a way to limit the string text size for all columns in a data.frame, without having to loop through each column and using something like str_trunc one column at a time?   For example the dataframe below, can I limit all text size to just 5 characters without having to do it one column at a time.  If this had like 50 columns truncating one column at a time would be difficult.

```
g1 = data.frame ( 
  gene = c( "aaaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaa","a","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"),
  value = c("1fdfdfdsfdsfdsfds","2fdfdfdfdsfds00","fdfdfds3","5ffffffffffff","0")
)
```

I tried something like this but failed.   `lapply(g1, str_trunc, 5)`

Would be great if, with one go, I can limit any string in the dataframe to just 5 characters. so for example the first cell , row 1, column 1 would be just aaaaa

thanks.

Comment: What is your expected ouptut

Comment: @akrun expected is that all string is limited to 5 characters only. sorry will update to make it more clear.

Comment: The `lapply` command does that? or `str_trunc(as.matrix(g1), 5)`

Comment: I have a doubt for some elements which are less than width 5.  Do you want to keep it as that or fill it with something?

Comment: Is this just for display purposes?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 correct.  The tables in my markdown gets hammered when I get long strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OP's code, the `str_trunc` by default uses `ellipsis = "..."`.  If we change it to blank (`""`), it should give the same output as above.  The output of `lapply` is a `list`, so we can assign it back to the data.frame or wrap with `data.frame` to convert the `list` to `data.frame`

```
library(stringr)
g1[] <- lapply(g1, str_trunc, 5, ellipsis = "")
g1
#   gene value
#1 aaaaa 1fdfd
#2 aaaaa 2fdfd
#3 aaaaa fdfdf
#4     a 5ffff
#5 bbbbb     0
```

Or we can use `base R` by converting the `data.frame` to `matrix` and use `substr` from `base R` without a loop

```
g1[] <- substr(as.matrix(g1), 1, 5)
g1
#   gene value
#1 aaaaa 1fdfd
#2 aaaaa 2fdfd
#3 aaaaa fdfdf
#4     a 5ffff
#5 bbbbb     0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
library(stringr)
g1 %>%  
      mutate(across(everything(), str_sub, 1, 5))
#   gene value
#1 aaaaa 1fdfd
#2 aaaaa 2fdfd
#3 aaaaa fdfdf
#4     a 5ffff
#5 bbbbb     0
```

If we have a `dplyr` version `<` 1.0.0, an option is `mutate_all`

```
g1 %>%
    mutate_all(str_sub, 1, 5)
```

Comment: across is an interesting function! It looks like I only have version: dplyr_0.8.5 though. However the first solution works.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` or `substring` :

```
g1[] <- lapply(g1, substr, 1, 5)
#OR
#g1[] <- lapply(g1, substring, 1, 5)
g1
#   gene value
#1 aaaaa 1fdfd
#2 aaaaa 2fdfd
#3 aaaaa fdfdf
#4     a 5ffff
#5 bbbbb     0
```

Comment: but results with a list instead of a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Base R anonymous function coercing factor types to characters in order to apply the substring function:

```
data.frame(lapply(g1, function(x){
      if(is.character(x) | is.factor(x)){
       x <- substring(x, 1, 5)
      }else{
        x
      }
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: What you've done is unnecessary. The first thing the `substring` function does is converts the input using `as.character`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 thank you I didn't know that :) ! edited above !