# Limiting characters in cells to a specific number while exporting data to a .csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

This is regarding an issue that I'm facing while exporting data to a `.csv` file. I'm working with a large dataframe in R. It contains few cells with characters greater than **32767**, which is apparently the maximum that a cell can accomodate. When I export the data to a `.csv` file the content of these cells spills over into the next row. The dataframe however looks completely fine once the `.csv` file is imported into RStudio. Is there a way to limit the number of characters in each cell to **32767** while exporting the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question in the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605096/limit-string-length-of-all-cells-in-a-dataframe).

Let's say `df` is the dataframe which I want to export to a `.csv` file. The following code does the job

```
df <- as.data.frame(substr(as.matrix(df), 1, 32767))
write.csv(df, <file>, rownames = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split long strings into *n* columns with *x* characters each, for example:

```
# example data
d <- data.frame(x = c("longstring", "anotherlongstring"))
d
#                   x
# 1        longstring
# 2 anotherlongstring

x = 6
n = 3
res <- read.fwf(file = textConnection(d$x), widths = rep(x, n))
res
#       V1     V2    V3
# 1 longst   ring  <NA>
# 2 anothe rlongs tring
```